# i could not find my fault in youtube json video list parse ..where is my fault?

Tags: ios, json, swift

when I type this code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if segDisplayedContent.selectedSegmentIndex == 0  {
            return videosArray.count
        }
    }
```

the error said `Missing a function expected to return "int"` 
"
 pls help me to fix it

Comment: you return int just if the condition is true. to fix the problem you have to return int if the condition is false

Answer (score 3):

This method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

has to return an Int.

When the program enters your "if" condition, an Int is properly returned:

```
return videosArray.count
```

But what happens when the control flow doesn't enter the "if" condition? Nothing is returned, and it's not acceptable by the compiler: you have to also return an Int.

A simple example, just to illustrate:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
    if segDisplayedContent.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 { 
        return videosArray.count 
    } 
    return 0
}
```

In this simple example, we return videosArray.count when the "if" condition is true, and return 0 when the "if" condition is false.